# Laravel whereIn with with()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I want to pass in array of `ids` and get all the `category` of that `ids` with all the banners of that `category`

I have defined relationship in `ProductMainCategory.php` Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductMainCategory extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function banners()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategoryBanner', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

The `ProductCategoryBanner.php` Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategoryBanner extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];
}
```

And in My controller

```
   //get distinct main_categories by id
    $main_category_ids = Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)
                                ->select('main_category_id')
                                ->distinct()
                                ->pluck('main_category_id')
                                ->toArray(); 

    //get main_category with banners (error query)
    $main_categories_with_images = ProductMainCategory::whereIn('id', $main_category_ids)
                                                      ->with(array('banners'=>function($query){
                                                            $query->select('id','image');
                                                       }))
                                                      ->get();

    //this query works, but it'll give all the categories but i want only passed id's categories
    $main_categories_with_images = ProductMainCategory::with('banners')
                                                  ->get();
```

I'm getting the data but banners are empty

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Grocery & Staples",
            "admin_id": 1,
            "banners": [] //getting empty array
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Fruits & Vegetables",
            "admin_id": 1,
            "banners": [] //getting empty array
        }
    ]

//actual result without $query->select('id','image'); is
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Grocery & Staples",
        "admin_id": 1,
        "banners": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category_id": "1",
                "image": "link 1",
                "admin_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "category_id": "1",
                "image": "link 2",
                "admin_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Fruits & Vegetables",
        "admin_id": 1,
        "banners": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "category_id": "2",
                "image": "link 3",
                "admin_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "category_id": "2",
                "image": "link 4",
                "admin_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It's `whereIn()`, not `wareIn()`

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin my bad with the typo, i have updated my post now the problem is `select()` in `with()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $main_categories_with_images = ProductMainCategory::whereIn('id', $main_category_ids)
                                                  ->with(array('banners'=>function($query){
                                                        $query->select('id','image');
                                                   }))
                                                  ->get();
```

Change `WareIn` to `WhereIn`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategoryBanner extends Model
  {
  protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

  public function mainCategory() { return $this->belongsTo('ProductMainCategory')->select(['id','image'‌​]); }
 }
```

Comment: not an error i'm not getting the data if i use `$query->select('id','image');`, please check my json

Comment: @MrRobot is can you please post the model too?

Comment: use `ProductMainCategory::with('banners')->get()` to get desired results

Comment: but i want only `id` and `image` fields from banners not all fields

Comment: public function banners()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ProductMainCategory')->select(['id','name']);
}   in your model of banners

Comment: @MrRobot post your model banners too

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
 //get main_category with banners (error query)
    $main_categories_with_images = ProductMainCategory::whereIn('id', $main_category_ids)
                                                      ->with(array('banners'=>function($query){
                                                            $query->select('id','image');
                                                       }))
                                                      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo after `ProductMainCategory` : `wareIn()`, It should be `whereIn()`